# How to remove empty space left after deleting items in a recycler view for android?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a very simple recyclerview with the following layout:-

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/address_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/address_recyclerview"></include>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Wher my recycler view layout is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adr_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    />
```

This is the code I am using to delete the item from the recycler view:-

```
 private void removeItem(UserInfo list) {
        int current_position = listData.indexOf(list);
        listData.remove(current_position);
        notifyItemRemoved(current_position);
    }
```

My Linear Layout is within a Scroll View.Now when I delete a item inside the recycler view the item gets deleted but after the deletion empty space is left behind.How do I auto delete this space when the item inside the recycler view is deleted?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: debug and check size of list after deleting item is reduced by one or not.

and also try notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 2):

Try adding notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
after notifyItemRemoved(current_position).

```
 private void removeItem(UserInfo list) {
    int current_position = listData.indexOf(list);
    listData.remove(current_position);
    notifyItemRemoved(current_position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged (current_position, getItemCount());
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have empty space after delete?

Comment: What is the recyclerview item layout like? what are your adapter and viewholder like?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you set setHasFixedSize to true, so try to make it false setHasFixedSize(false) and it will remove that space